# Why am I getting a NullPointer Exception with my array?

Tags: java, arrays, class, nullpointerexception

Can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting an error here. It lets me put in the input, but then quits out and says theres a NullPointerException at the line that starts with "emp[i].setName".

```
    String dpt, salary, name;
    Manager[] emp = new Manager[3];

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name");
        emp[i].setName(name);
```

Comment: because you make an array of managers but you never set each element of the array to a `new Manager()`.

Comment: The array is full of nulls...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an array in Java, all of the elements are nulls (for non-primitive types anyway; ints, for example will just be `0`). If you want to create an array with actual objects, you need to create them. One option (and the simplest) is to create them in a loop like this:

```
String dpt, salary, name;
Manager[] emp = new Manager[3];

for (int i=0; i<emp.length; i++)
{
  emp[i] = new Manager(); // Create the object
  name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name");
  emp[i].setName(name);
}
```

Also notice that I use `emp.length` in the `for` loop instead of just the number 3. This is so that if the size of your manager array changes, you won't end up with `ArrayIndexOutOfRangeException` (trying to access an element in the array that doesn't exist).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) has a much more detailed answer that is definitely worth reading.

Comment: `When you create an array in Java, all of the elements are nulls` Only for non-primitive types.

Comment: Actually, the question I marked as a duplicate has more details than "what's a null pointer"

Comment: @Zarwan, edited. That part about strings is correct, yes?

Comment: Strings are not a primitive type.

Comment: Gah. Friggin Java. You're right.